# How to dynamically build <<<EOD string in PHP

Tags: php

I want to build my string dynamically depending on the results from the DB. So far I have created something like this:

```
        $feed = Some essential xml that needs to go here;
        for ($a = 0; $a < count($images); $a++)
        {
            if ($a == 0)
            {
                $image_type = "Main";
            }
            else
            {
                $image_type = "PT". $a;
            }
            $feed += <<<EOD
  <Message>
    <MessageID>1</MessageID>
    <OperationType>Update</OperationType>
    <ProductImage>
        <SKU>{$data['sku']}</SKU>
        <ImageType>{$image_type}</ImageType>
        <ImageLocation>{$images[$a]}</ImageLocation>
    </ProductImage>
  </Message>
EOD;

        }

        $feed += <<<EOD
</AmazonEnvelope>        
EOD;
echo $feed;
```

This example of course returns nothing however I wanted to present my code in the way that I would like it to work. Do would I build the $feed string dynamically in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PHP string concatenation is done with the `.` operator, not the `+`. Therefore concatenate and assign is also `.=`, not `+=`. Fix that in both relevant lines and it'll work fine.

The underlying reason for the different operator here is that, unlike most other popular languages, PHP is weak-typed. The `+` operator is as such reserved for mathematical operations, so PHP can handle these 2 different lines 'correctly':

```
echo '123'+'123';    // Shows 246
echo '123'.'123';    // Shows 123123
```

[Example](https://eval.in/188548).

Comment: Javascript is also weak-typed, but still uses `+` for both addition and concatenation. Of course, this frequently causes bugs.

Comment: Definitions are loose here. Javascript has less implicit conversions, specifically from `string` to `int`, allowing it to be more strict in this regard and not require the extra operator. C++ is strongly typed but allows all these behaviours through operator overloading, and can seem extremely weakly typed through conversion operator overloading.